# Как работает следующая CSS разметка?

Tags: css

Не могу понять как работает следующая разметка. Помогите пожалуйста)

```
.splash-video-wrapper {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77778vh;
  min-height: 200vw;
  max-height: 200vw;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**top: 50%** - это отступ самой левой верней точки элемента от верхнего края браузера, а 50% - это высота элемента с классом splash-video-wrapper или 50% - это от высоты всего экрана?

И второе, если убрать **{ min-width: 177.77778vh; min-height: 200vw; max-height: 200vw; }** то элемент растянется не на всю ширину экрана, почему так?

И третье, если убрать **{ transform: translate(-50%, -50%); }**, то элемент вообще не показывается.

Comment: все ответы в [Справочнике CSS](https://webref.ru/css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так:

```
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Используется для центрирование контейнера относительно, предка с свойством `position` отличным от `static`, если предка нет, то отсчет координат ведется от края окна браузера. Подробней [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/netcracker/blog/277433/).

Т.е. `top: 50%; left: 50%;` это отступ 50% высоты контейнера предка, а не `.splash-video-wrapper`. Т.к. контейнер теперь смещен на половину высоты и ширины предка, а не себя, его необходимо сдвинуть обратно (влево и вверх) на половину своей ширины и высоты, это делается с помощью `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.

```
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 177.77778vh;
  min-height: 200vw;
  max-height: 200vw;
```

`vh`, `vw` - относительные единицы измерения. Эти единицы вычисляются относительно размеров окна браузера.

Заданно `width: 100vw;` - ширина окна браузера (или `iframe` если используется что-то типа jsfiddle.net). Что сводит на нет выравнивание по центру относительно ширины предка. При этом `.splash-video-wrapper` не может быть меньше 177.77778% относительно ширины браузера. Тоже самое про `height: 100vh;`, только относительно высоты окна браузера.